# App Engine OAuth Callback to a Custom Protocol

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I'm working on connecting an Android application to an App Engine server with OAuth. The common way of doing this is specifying a custom, non-existant protocol for the callback URL (e.g., myapp://) and setting the Android Manifest to filter intents with data pointing to that protocol.

My issue is, App Engine seems to error on any callback URL with a protocol other than HTTP or HTTPS with the error "Invalid Callback URL". Am I being an idiot, or does App Engine not allow this? How can I work around it?

Comment: "Seems to error" isn't very useful - what actual behavior do you observe when trying this? Can't you set it to an actual HTTP URL (such as http://localhost/foo, or a valid address on a domain you own reserved for the purpose) and filter for that instead?

Comment: Sorry for the vague language. It does not redirect me, instead presenting a simple response (on the google.com domain) that reads "Invalid Callback URL." If I use an HTTPS protocol to a non-existent domain, it works just fine, but only for the default Android browser and the user has to choose between my app and their browsers when opening the link, as either could be used. Which is sub-optimal by a long shot.

Comment: Have you watched this year's IO talk on using App Engine with Android? There are other ways to sign the user in using the credentials stored in their associated Google account.

Comment: Yeah, this limits the app to 2.1+, though. And while I would say that was fine now, a year ago (when the app was released) very few phones ran 2.1. So I've got a couple hundred people that would be left high and dry if I were to remove support for 1.5 and 1.6. Again, possible, but not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the feedback I've gotten, looks like this is impossible. Recommended route is the Accounts API.